# Wrong info returning from a function

Tags: c++, function, pointers, char, printf

I have a problem at using a function that returns a char. This is the code of the function, which gathers 3 chars(c1,c2,c3) into 1 (infotot):

```
char gatherinfo(char *c1,char *c2,char *c3){
    char infotot[256];
    int n=sprintf(infotot,"%s;%s;%s;",c1,c2,c3);
    return *infotot;
}
```

And in main I have this code in order to access to the function:

```
char info[256];
    *info=gatherinfo(c1,c2,c3);
```

Where c1, c2, and c3 are defined as:

```
char *c1,*c2,*c3;
```

In the function, infotot takes the right value:

```
*infotot="c1;c2;c3;"
```

But the problem comes in main, where info takes the following value;

```
*info="lÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ"
```

Where the first letter "l" corresponds to the first letter of c1. How could I solve it in order to have info="c1;c2;c3;"?

Comment: You're assigning a single `char`, not a string, which is why only the first letter appears

Comment: Are the pointers you pass pointers to a single character? You know that the format `"%s"` expects a C-style *string*? I.e. an array of characters terminated by zero. It's hard to say anything without a proper [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but it looks like *undefined behavior* to me.

Comment: `return *infotot;` is equivalent to `return infotot[0];`. `*info=gatherinfo(c1,c2,c3);` is equivalent to `info[0]=gatherinfo(c1,c2,c3);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`char infotot[256];` will be deallocated when `gatherinfo` returns.

I would allocate the destination buffer in main and pass it to the function:

```
char info[256];
gatherinfo(info,c1,c2,c3);

void gatherinfo(char *infotot,char *c1,char *c2,char *c3){
    sprintf(infotot,"%s;%s;%s;",c1,c2,c3);
}
```

To improve this, you could use `std::string`.

Comment: Thank you! It worked perfectly. I want to avoid to use string because later I will need that information in char mode, so in order to avoid the future str to char conversion this solution is perfect.

Answer (score 4):

`gatherinfo` is returning a single char, not a string. You are assigning that char to the first element of the array `info`.

This array isn't null terminated, so when you print it, you see the first element followed by garbage.

You must return a `std::string`. A std::string can be copied.

```
std::string gatherinfo(char *c1,char *c2,char *c3){
    char infotot[256];
    sprintf(infotot,"%s;%s;%s;",c1,c2,c3);
    return infotot; // Here infotot is used to construct the std::string returned by the function. Same as return std::string(infotot);
}
```

You can also use the std::string operator + (concatenation)

```
std::string gatherinfo(char *c1,char *c2,char *c3){
    return std::string(c1) + ";" + c2 + ";" + c3 + ";";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`gatherinfo` returns a single character (not a string of characters).

You write this single character (which will be the first char of `c1`) into the first character of `info` - but critically, you don't write a null character afterwards.

The fix is that `gatherinfo` should return `std::string`.  (And I *suspect* that it should take it's arguments as `const std::string&` too).  So:

```
std::string gatherinfo(
   const std::string& c1, const std::string& c2, const std::string& c3){
    return c1 + ';' + c2 + ';' + c3
}
```